# Relation between storage and database - Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm facing yet another issue.

I'm using firebase db to store text and firebase storage to store files. And here comes my issue.

**Q**: How to fetch a correct image **from storage** when fetching particular element **from database**?

Here's my attempt:

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('companyImages/companyImage' + 123);
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ I dont have access to id yet :(
const task = storageRef.put(companyImage);

task.on('state_changed', () => {
  const percentage = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100; 
                               // ^^^^^^^^^^^^ not sure if i even need this
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
}, () => {
  firebase.database().ref('offers').push(values);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ now I could retrieve id from it with .key but its too late
});
```

As you can see, first what Im doing is uploading the image and when it's succesful, Im starting to upload the data to database.

Still, it doesnt work as it is supposed to. When uploading image I have to name it with a correct `id` to retrieve it easily later, in components.

It may look a lil bit complex but will appreciate any kind of help. Any suggestion or hint.

**Should I** firstly upload data to DB and then image to the storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the push ID before you upload the file – you can also just save the download URL of the returned snapshot at `task.snapshot.downloadURL` so you don't have to retrieve the file from storage using the storage ref.

```
const offerRef = firebase.database().ref('offers').push();
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`companyImages/${offerRef.key}`);
const task = storageRef.put(companyImage);

task.on('state_changed', (snap) => {
  const percentage = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100; 
}, (error) => {
  console.log(err);
}, () => {
  offerRef.set(values);
});
```

Comment: Ah it always catches me out, maybe now I'll remember.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using .getDownloadURL(). Then push all your uploadedfileDownloadURL's into an object or array and then store that into your database. So in the future you can access this object or array from, lets say your user/ProfilePHotos, and then in your app level code you can just use the DownloadURL as a uri links inside an image tag!

In this example I am using react-native, I upload multiple photos, save the download URL each time in an array, then set the array to firebase under the users account.

```
export const userVehiclePhotoUploadRequest = (photos, user, year) => dispatch => {
    console.log('Inside vehiclePhotoUpload Actions', photos, user)

    let referenceToUploadedPhotos = [];

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        photos.map(ele => {
            let mime = 'application/octet-stream'

            let uri = ele.uri
            let uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri
            let sessionId = new Date().getTime()
            let uploadBlob = null
            let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('vehicleImages/' + `${user.account.uid}`).child(`${sessionId}`)

            fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
                .then((data) => {
                    return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` })
                })
                .then((blob) => {
                    uploadBlob = blob
                    return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime })
                })
                .then(() => {
                    uploadBlob.close()
                    return imageRef.getDownloadURL()
                })
                .then((url) => {
                    referenceToUploadedPhotos.push(url)
                    console.log('ARRAY OF URLS WHILE PUSHING', referenceToUploadedPhotos)
                    resolve(url)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    reject(error)
                })
        })
    })
        .then(() => {
            //I did this to not go home until photos are done uploading. 

            let vehicles;
            firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.account.uid + `/allVehicles/allVehiclesArray`).limitToFirst(1).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
                // ******** This method is straight from their docs ********
                // ******** It returns whatever is found at the path xxxxx/users/user.uid ********
                vehicles = snapshot.val();
            }).then(() => {
                console.log('ARRAY OF URLS BEFORE SETTING', referenceToUploadedPhotos)
                // let lastVehicle = vehicles.length - 1;
                firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.account.uid + `/allVehicles/allVehiclesArray/` + `${Object.keys(vehicles)[0]}` + `/photosReference`).set({
                    referenceToUploadedPhotos
                }).then(() => {
                    dispatch(loginRequest(user.account))
                })
            })


        })


};
```

And then in your code, lets say inside a map of the user's information...

```
 { ele.photosReference !== undefined ? dynamicAvatar = { uri: `${ele.photosReference.referenceToUploadedPhotos[0]}` } : undefined }
```